# Disable FileCost in MSI using ORCA

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, orca

I have a need to disable the disk space check on an MSI for deployment. I see where the FileCost options are in the MSI in ORCA, and am able to create a transform, but I constantly receive errors when running the MSI with transform.

How do I properly disable this?

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of Windows installer actions that rely on file costing. I'm not sure why you would want to disable it.

It sounds like you may be already doing it, but I would go through all of the associated actions and condition them to 0 in both the Execute and UI Sequences.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368593(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: reason being that we have a cloud-attached SAN, and when trying to install a monitoring agent at system boot (or even at the CLI), the costing process is taking that SAN into account, which we don't want it to do.

Comment: Normally a network attached device is not considered in file costing unless you're trying to install a file to that location. Microsoft does not recommend installing to network locations.

Comment: which we aren't.  it's prior to the drive selection